# mkDerivation use cmake in buildPhase

Tags: nix, vcpkg, nixpkgs

I'm trying to create a derivation using nix files, and I'm a little stuck. A package I'm trying to install has a sh file in its repo to build it, and this sh file is running CMake with some arguments.

More specifically, this package is vcpkg.

Here's my `vcpkg.nix` file:

```
{ gcc11Stdenv, fetchFromGitHub, ninja, cmake, bash }:

gcc11Stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "vcpkg-2021.05.12";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "microsoft";
    repo = "vcpkg";
    rev = "2021.05.12";
    sha256 = "0290fp9nvmbqpgr33rnchn5ngsq4fdll2psvh0bqf0324w2qpsjw";
  };

  buildPhase = ''
    ./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh -useSystemBinaries
  '';
}
```

When running it with `nix-shell -p 'with (import <nixpkgs> {}); callPackage ./vcpkg.nix {}'`, I get this error:

```
configuring
no configure script, doing nothing
building
Could not find cmake. Please install it (and other dependencies) with:
sudo apt-get install cmake ninja-build
error: builder for '/nix/store/riq6vjdhv4z3xvzp8g597xjgwf2rvm03-vcpkg-2021.05.12.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 9 log lines:
       > unpacking sources
       > unpacking source archive /nix/store/ycfd6vbgh3s1vy11hfb17b8x33rqj7aw-source
       > source root is source
       > patching sources
       > configuring
       > no configure script, doing nothing
       > building
       > Could not find cmake. Please install it (and other dependencies) with:
       > sudo apt-get install cmake ninja-build
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/riq6vjdhv4z3xvzp8g597xjgwf2rvm03-vcpkg-2021.05.12.drv'.
```

Then, I thought of making `cmake` and `ninja` available to `buildPhase` so the script can use those binaries by adding `buildInputs = [cmake ninja];`, but I then get this error:

```
configuring
fixing cmake files...
cmake flags: -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALEDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/locale -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/libexec -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/doc/vcpkg -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INFODIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/info -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/man -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/sbin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/lib -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0025=NEW -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT= -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_STRIP=/nix/store/854jyvxrvpdpbfn2zaba1v2qgqkxipyh-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/strip -DCMAKE_RANLIB=/nix/store/854jyvxrvpdpbfn2zaba1v2qgqkxipyh-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/ranlib -DCMAKE_AR=/nix/store/854jyvxrvpdpbfn2zaba1v2qgqkxipyh-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/ar -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12  
CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/nix-build-vcpkg-2021.05.12.drv-0/source" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
error: builder for '/nix/store/76djky7f3xy6ym6v3qlmy941z0bjb8xw-vcpkg-2021.05.12.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 9 log lines:
       > unpacking sources
       > unpacking source archive /nix/store/ycfd6vbgh3s1vy11hfb17b8x33rqj7aw-source
       > source root is source
       > patching sources
       > configuring
       > fixing cmake files...
       > cmake flags: -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF -DCMAKE_FIND_USE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=OFF -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALEDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/locale -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/libexec -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/doc/vcpkg -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INFODIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/info -DCMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/share/man -DCMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/sbin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_DIR=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12/lib -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0025=NEW -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT= -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_STRIP=/nix/store/854jyvxrvpdpbfn2zaba1v2qgqkxipyh-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/strip -DCMAKE_RANLIB=/nix/store/854jyvxrvpdpbfn2zaba1v2qgqkxipyh-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/ranlib -DCMAKE_AR=/nix/store/854jyvxrvpdpbfn2zaba1v2qgqkxipyh-cctools-binutils-darwin-949.0.1/bin/ar -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/nix/store/mp38jl4fkv0gqnqhz7a3agx4flwda59n-vcpkg-2021.05.12
       > CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/nix-build-vcpkg-2021.05.12.drv-0/source" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
       > Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/76djky7f3xy6ym6v3qlmy941z0bjb8xw-vcpkg-2021.05.12.drv'.
```

It seems that adding `cmake` to `buildInputs` makes nix try to configure the project using `cmake`, but this is not what I'm trying to do since vcpkg don't simply have a `CMakeLists.txt` file in its repo.

Adding `inherit cmake ninja;` didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent cmake from changing the configure phase by setting `dontUseCmakeConfigure=true` in your derivation.

From the [nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/):

> 6.7.29. cmake
>
> Overrides the default configure phase to run the CMake command. By default, we use the Make generator of CMake. In addition, dependencies are added automatically to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH so that packages are correctly detected by CMake. Some additional flags are passed in to give similar behavior to configure-based packages. You can disable this hook’s behavior by setting configurePhase to a custom value, or by setting dontUseCmakeConfigure. cmakeFlags controls flags passed only to CMake. By default, parallel building is enabled as CMake supports parallel building almost everywhere. When Ninja is also in use, CMake will detect that and use the ninja generator.